# I want to replace the Year to all 2000, but failing to replace the year

Tags: sql, oracle

I did try to use this query

```sql
UPDATE people
   SET BIRTHDATE = replace (BIRTHDATE, '%:00 2%' ,'%:00 2000')
 WHERE BIRTHDATE IN (select birthdate from people)
```

current data

```
BIRTHDATE
Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 **2020**
Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 **2130**
Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 **1920**
```

Comment: What is the datatype of column `birthdate`?

Comment: this is varchar2

Comment: Thanks. Also can you please show us sample data and expected results for the two tables involved? It is quite unclear what the data structure is.

Comment: I want to update like this, 

From:
Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2020

To:
Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2000

I just want to change the Year to 2000 without changing the Date and Month

Comment: This way we know what you need to get, but it's hard to help you without knowing where you are starting from. As said, sample data would be useful.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including DDL statements for (a minimal example of) your table, DML statements for the current data and an English description (not code) of the operation you wish to perform and the corresponding output you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `birthdate` is a string, and you want to replace the 4 rightmost digits that start with `'2'` with `'2000'`, a solution is to use `regexp_replace()`:

```
update crm_customer_data
set birthdate = regexp_replace(birthdate, '2\d{3}$' ,'2000')
```

Regexp detail:

```
2       the number '2'
\d{3}   3 digits
$       end of the string
```

Without sample data it is unclear what is the purpose of the `in` condition with the subquery, so I left it apart for now.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=58f0c94539255d7ba33808aa37c7c05d)**:

```
select regexp_replace('Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2020', '2\d{3}$', '2000') from dual
```

```
| REGEXP_REPLACE('MONJAN2700:00:002020','2\D{3}$','2000') |
| :------------------------------------------------------ |
| Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2000                                |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple string functions:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE crm_customer_data ( birthdate ) AS
SELECT 'Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2020' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2130' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 1920' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2020' FROM DUAL;
```

**Update**:

```sql
UPDATE crm_customer_data
SET    BIRTHDATE = SUBSTR( BIRTHDATE, 1, LENGTH( BIRTHDATE ) - 4 ) || '2000'
-- WHERE  BIRTHDATE IN (select birthdate from people)
-- AND    BIRTHDATE LIKE '%2___'
```

**Output**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM  crm_customer_data
```

> ```
> | BIRTHDATE                |
> | :----------------------- |
> | Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2000 |
> | Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2000 |
> | Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2000 |
> | Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cac84bc2d04e90a5fcda79722bba28f6)*